# Rounding with BigDecimal

Tags: groovy, bigdecimal

Why this fails?

```
assert 1.0G.divide(12.0G, 4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP) == 1.0G.divide(12.0G, new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
```

fails with:

```
|  Condition not satisfied:

1.0G.divide(12.0G, 4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP) == 1.0G.divide(12.0G, new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
     |                                      |       |             |
     0.0833                                 false   0.08333       precision=4 roundingMode=HALF_UP
```

Comment: FYI, I've removed the Java tag because this code is pure Groovy.  But here's the equivalent effect in Java: http://ideone.com/jaMhvV.

Comment: In Java this should fail because you are using `==` instead of `equals`. I don't know what Groovy does.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Groovy `==` is effectively Java `equals`, with a pre-check that the LHS isn't `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The first part:

```
1.0G.divide(12.0G, 4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

uses signature of `divide` method with **scale**:

```
BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)
```

But second uses MathContext that uses **precision**, and that is a different thing.